# Are there unique names for the different types of Kitsune?

Tags: mythical-creatures, japanese, shinto

> There are thirteen different kinds of Kitsune, each with a corresponding element, listed as follows: Heaven (or Celestial or Prime), Void (or Dark), Wind, Spirit, Fire, Earth, River, Ocean, Mountain, Forest, Thunder, Time and Sound.
>
> Information found [here](http://www.mythicalcreaturesguide.com/page/Kitsune), 5/7/2018.

Are there unique names for the type of kitsune in relation to the corresponding element?